# Display web api exception in angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, jwt

I am working on a project with web api backend and angular2 front end. I am having an issue showing the server error in angular2. Every time the server error it throws CORS error.

```
Here is my sample api

public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Visitor model)
{
  if (model == null) throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
  {
      ReasonPhrase = "Missing model in post"
  });
  _registerService.register(model);
  return Ok(model);    
}


And here is my angular2 service


addVisit(visit: Visit) {

let siteId = visit.siteId;
let body = JSON.stringify(visit);
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.authHttp
    .post(`${this._visitorsUrl}` + siteId, body, options)
    .map(res => {
        res.json();
        console.log("map: " + JSON.stringify(res.json()));
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

}

When the model is null it return error 502 or CORS error but when the model is not null it will retrn 200

My problem is how can I display the error that the server return.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug fix in .net Core 2.2 that fixes the bug that "No CORS headers sent in case of error 500", a bug that results in a CORS error.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/2378

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you add something like

```
error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error;
```

on the if where you check for null? I use it inside a .subscribe to a .map but I believe it is something like this what you are looking for?

Comment: I already did that but still not working 

  handleError (error: any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }

Comment: Here you have another example basically doing the same, check getCountriesByRegion(), if it does not show up it could be because of something else? http://www.waynehong.com/javascript/angular-2-service-example-typescript/

Answer (score -2):

You should convert the response to InternalServerError and return Content as shown in the code snippet below

```
throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            {
                ReasonPhrase = "Missing model in post",
                Content = new StringContent("Missing Model in post")
            });
```

You will then be able to see the error in statusText property of error in angular.

Comment: What did it return?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load 500